# Helm: Executing command on other containers in Job

Tags: laravel, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I want to utilize [Charts Hooks](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/charts_hooks.md)'s `post-install` to do some action on my deployment's container.

For example, I have a `php-fpm` container that consists of a `Laravel` application, and I want to run `php artisan key:gen` on install. Since it's a one time command so I couldn't place it on the `postStart` lifecycle, otherwise it would keep overwriting the `APP_KEY`.

How can I use ***Charts Hooks*** to achieve it? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Is it possible to have a endpoint in your laravel application to do `key:gen` ?. If possible, we can fire that call from installation job

Comment: In that case, how to handle the security of that endpoint? Only open the endpoint when we don't have `APP_KEY`? Is there better option? So that I can handle other cases at well

Comment: @CloudSohJunFu where is the APP_KEY stored ? If it is stored in a file, you can call a script in postStart lifecycle and call `php artisan key:gen` if the key file is not present.

Answer (score 2):

Your job needs to run a container that contains `kubectl` and you would execute this script to exec into another container. Since `kubectl exec` [doesn't support selection by labels](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/8876) you need to retrieve the pod name beforehand:

```
$pod=$(kubectl get pods --no-headers -o custom-columns=":metadata.name" -l YOUR-LABELS=YOUR-VALUES)
kubectl exec $pod php artisan key:gen
```

Answer (score 1):

If you think about the lifecycle of this key: if there are multiple pod replicas they need to agree on what the key is; and if you delete and recreate the pod, it needs to be using the same key it was using before.  (A quick Google search comes up with some good descriptions of [what this key is actually used for](https://tighten.co/blog/app-key-and-you); if it's encrypting session cookies, for example, every copy of the pod really needs to agree.)

This suggests a setup where you generate the key once, store it in a Kubernetes Secret, and make it available to pods.  Conveniently, ["any variable in your `.env` file can be overridden by external environment variables"](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/configuration#environment-configuration), and [you can set an environment variable from a secret value](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/distribute-credentials-secure/#define-container-environment-variables-using-secret-data).  There isn't a great way to make Helm generate the secret itself in a way that will be saved.

So, putting these pieces together: in your pod spec (inside your deployment spec) you need to get the environment variable from the secret.

```
env:
  - name: APP_KEY
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: "{{ .Release.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Name }}"
        key: app-key
```

Then you need to create a secret to hold the key.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: "{{ .Release.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Name }}"
data:
  app-key: {{ printf "base64:%s" .Values.appKey | b64enc }}
```

And finally create the file holding the key.  This should not be checked in as part of your chart.

```
echo "appKey: $(dd if=/dev/urandom bs=32 count=1 | base64)" > values-local.yaml
```

When you go to install your chart, use this values file

```
helm install ./charts/myapp -f values-local.yaml
```

There are a couple of other reasonable approaches that involve injecting the whole `.env` file as a ConfigMap or Secret, or extending your Docker image to generate this file on its own from values that get passed into it, or using an init container to generate the file before the main container starts.  The point is that pods come and go, and need to be able to configure themselves when they start up; using `kubectl exec` in the way you're suggesting isn't great practice.

Answer (score -1):

You can define a Job that will be run only once when Helm chart is installed:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: "{{.Release.Name}}"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{.Release.Service | quote }}
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{.Release.Name | quote }}
    app.kubernetes.io/version: {{ .Chart.AppVersion }}
    helm.sh/chart: "{{.Chart.Name}}-{{.Chart.Version}}"
  annotations:
    # This is what defines this resource as a hook. Without this line, the
    # job is considered part of the release.
    "helm.sh/hook": post-install
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "-5"
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": hook-succeeded
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: "{{.Release.Name}}"
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{.Release.Service | quote }}
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{.Release.Name | quote }}
        helm.sh/chart: "{{.Chart.Name}}-{{.Chart.Version}}"
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Never
      containers:
      - name: post-install-job
        image: "alpine:3.3"
        command: ["/bin/sleep","{{default "10" .Values.sleepyTime}}"]
```

If you want to run job every time you upgrade chart - you can specify "post-upgrade" hook.
Read more here: https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/charts_hooks.md

Comment: As I said, I want to run command from the Job(alpine) on my container(php-fpm, mysql) and so on. Can you provide an example in my scenario?

Comment: I just gave an example. You have to complete it yourself.

Comment: You didn't give an example, you just copied from the documentation.